# Use a sequence to populate multiple columns with successive values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

**How can I use default constraints, triggers, or some other mechanism to automatically insert multiple successive values from a sequence into multiple columns on the same row of a table?**

A standard use of a sequence in SQL Server is to combine it with default constraints on multiple tables to essentially get a cross-table identity. See for example the section "C. Using a Sequence Number in Multiple Tables" in the Microsoft documentation article "[Sequence Numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)".

This works great if you only want to get a single value from the sequence for each row inserted. But *sometimes* I want to get multiple successive values. So theoretically I would create a sequence and table like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE DocumentationIDs;

CREATE TABLE Product
    (
      ProductID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , ProductName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , MarketingDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ( NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs )
    , TechnicalDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ( NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs )
    , InternalDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ( NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs )
    );
```

Unfortunately this will insert the **same value** in all three columns. This is [by design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx#Anchor_1):

> If there are multiple instances of the NEXT VALUE FOR function specifying the same sequence generator within a single Transact-SQL statement, all those instances return the same value for a given row processed by that Transact-SQL statement. This behavior is consistent with the ANSI standard.

**Increment by hack**

The only [suggestion](http://bidn.com/blogs/KathiKellenberger/sql-server/2816/using-the-sequence-object-to-populate-two-columns) I could find online was to use a hack where you have the sequence increment by the number of columns you need to insert (three in my contrived example) and manually add to the `NEXT VALUE FOR` function in the default constraint:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE DocumentationIDs START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 3;

CREATE TABLE Product
    (
      ProductID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , ProductName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , MarketingDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ( NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs )
    , TechnicalDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ( ( NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs ) + 1 )
    , InternalDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ( ( NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs ) + 2 )
    )
```

This does **not** work for me because not all tables using my sequence require the same number of values.

Comment: Cannot you just use another sequence for other tables? How they are correlated that they need the same sequence? Second solution is to increment by max number of columns like 10, this should satisfy all tables but you will get gaps.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way using `AFTER INSERT` trigger is following.

Table definition need to be changed slighlty (`DocumentationID` columns should be defaulted to `0`, or allowed to be nullable):

```
CREATE TABLE Product
    (
      ProductID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , ProductName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , MarketingDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Product_1 DEFAULT (0)
    , TechnicalDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Product_2 DEFAULT (0)
    , InternalDocumentationID BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Product_3 DEFAULT (0)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
    );
```

And the trigger doing the job is following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Product_AfterInsert ON Product
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
        RETURN;

    CREATE TABLE #DocIDs
        (
        ProductID BIGINT NOT NULL
        , Num INT NOT NULL
        , DocID BIGINT NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (ProductID, Num)
        );

    INSERT INTO #DocIDs (ProductID, Num, DocID)
        SELECT
            i.ProductID
            , r.n
            , NEXT VALUE FOR DocumentationIDs OVER (ORDER BY i.ProductID, r.n)
        FROM INSERTED i
            CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) r(n)
            ;

    WITH Docs (ProductID, MarketingDocID, TechnicalDocID, InternalDocID)
    AS (
        SELECT ProductID, [1], [2], [3]
        FROM #DocIDs d
            PIVOT (MAX(DocID) FOR Num IN ([1], [2], [3])) pvt
    )
    UPDATE p
    SET
        p.MarketingDocumentationID = d.MarketingDocID
        , p.TechnicalDocumentationID = d.TechnicalDocID
        , p.InternalDocumentationID = d.InternalDocID
    FROM Product p
        JOIN Docs d ON d.ProductID = p.ProductID
        ;

END
```

Comment: _upd:_ However, such design seems odd a bit. Normally, if you have `Documentation` table, it should have identity PK column. With this you insert into this table first, and then you insert (or update) records in the `Product` using ID from `Documentation`.